# Sort a child list of parent list by parent list order in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to sort a child list of parent list by parent list order using Python.

```
parent_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
child_list = ['e', 'd', 'b']
```

Expected output:

```
child_list = ['b', 'd', 'e']
```

I tried like below:

```
child_list.sort(key = lambda i: parent_list.index(i))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: 'a' is not in list
```

Comment: That should work, and _does_ work in this example. Did you maybe run some other code that produced this error?

Comment: what are you trying to do? put the members of the sub-list in the same order they are in the parent-list?

Comment: try: `child_list.sort(key = lambda i: parent_list.index(i[0]))` will only work when the element is present in `parent_list`

Comment: Note that in cases where you're writing `key=lambda thing: something(thing)`, you can generally just write `key=something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the code you posted works (if it gives you an error, you must be using different code or different data), it's inefficient: the parent list needs to be searched from beginning to (potentially) end for every element in the child list. It doesn't matter for such a short list, but when the length of those lists gets in the thousands, you might start to notice.

A more efficient approach is to first create a dictionary out of the parent list, which maps elements to indices, and then use that dict for sorting.

```py
>>> indices = {i: e for e, i in enumerate(parent_list)}
>>> indices
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5}
>>> child_list.sort(key = lambda e: indices[e])
```

Comment: Thanks. As you said I got the error due to my other part of the code. sorry for the trouble.

Comment: If I have two list like this ``` parent_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] and 
child_list = ['e', 'd', 'b', 'k', 'j'] ``` , how can I drop(keys are not in parent list) ```'k' and 'j' ```elements from sorted child_list ?

Comment: `child_list = sorted(filter(lambda e: e in indices, child_list), key = lambda e: indices[e])` or `child_list = sorted((e for e in child_list if e in indices), key = ...)`